Conjecture: the integer cosets of ideals are Noetherian
I have strong evidence that this fact will help prove continuity of $\pi_2(n)$ the twin prime average counter on the naturals.  Continuity with respect to the Furstenberg topology that is.   See my recent post history under continuity for more details.
Let $U_1 \subset U_2 \subset \dots$.  This sequence must eventually stabilize where $U_i=a_i + b_i\Bbb{Z}$ are integer ring cosets of ideals.
It makes sense but how do we prove that $b_{i+1}$ divides $b_i$?
If $a +b\Bbb{Z} \subset c + d\Bbb{Z}$ then $b = \text{lcm}(b,d)$ by intersecting the two cosets.   Ok then so $d$ must divide $a-c$.  Or $a= c \pmod d$.   Since the ideals obviously stabilize, so too must the taken standard residue and we’re done.✅
So my question now becomes are either finite unions of cosets or arbitrary unions there of also Noetherian?
If arbitrary unions stabilize then I can work with open sets in Furstenberg topology.  But if it’s only finite unions that become stable when in the inclusion chain ⛓️‍ then I will have to do something with closed sets.   So really hoping for Noetherian arbitrary unions of cosets.

Clarification.
Let $\tau$ be a topology that is generated by cosets found in the Furstenberg topology, which is $\sigma = \langle a + b\Bbb{Z}: a,b \in \Bbb{Z}, b \neq 0 \rangle$.  In other words, $\tau$ forms a topology itself using some subset of the Furstenberg basis.
Now let $U_i = \bigcup_{j = 1}^{n_i} (a_j^i + b_j^i\Bbb{Z}), \ i \geq 1$ be a sequence of finite unions of basic sets such that $U_{i} \subset U_{i+1}$ for all $i \geq 1$.
Question.  Does the sequence $U_1 \subset U_2 \subset U_3 \dots$ stabilize to $U_n$ for some $n \geq 1$? I.e. for all $m \geq n$ we have that $U_m = U_n$?  In other words, are finite unions of basic open sets in $\tau$ Noetherian?
Attempt. I would guess the answer is a resounding "No!", because even though some cosets within the unions would stabilize, we could just keep adding in more random cosets so that the sequence just increases to some open set, not necessarily an entry in the chain.
Luckily, though I thought I needed this at one point in my Topo-NT problem, I found out that approach had other unrelated errors.  It is still kind of cool that coset chains are Noetherian.

You can try to prove that if $R$ is a ring, $I$ and $J$ are two ideals, and $a+I\subset b+J$ for some $a,b\in R$, then $I\subset J$.

@CaptainLama you may pick whatever generality works best in your answer.  Thx

Ok  finished proof of first conjecture, now how do we attack the union question?

I will think on the union question then probably post back an answer.  Thanks  to all those who supported

Started bounty.  Found an application in topological NT for this.

I guess your question will have more chances to be answered if you provide in its body all needed definitions.

@AlexRavsky Done ✅.  However, I added a note at the end explaining why I think the answer is "No".  On the other hand, perhaps Erdos covering systems have something to say about it.  Perhaps if you keep adding in random cosets, the union goes to $\Bbb{Z}$ which is a coset itself.  So I'm not 100% sure the answer is negative, and it's worth having it answered.

the answer to your second question is no. let $p_1,p_2,p_3,\dots$ enumerate the primes. then let $U_n=p_1\mathbb{Z}\cup\dots\cup p_n\mathbb{Z}$. then $U_n\subsetneq U_{n+1}$ for each $n$

@AtticusStonestrom I didn't see that!  Nice counter-example.

@AtticusStonestrom you're welcome to claim the bounty
